# The OP is missing his/her highlighting

Tags: feature-request, comments, user-interface, meta

In the designs of all sites, the original poster of the question is highlighted in comments, however in the new design of MSE, the highlighting is missing.  The OP looks just like any other user.

Example from MSE without highlighting:

> [image: screenshoot from MSE without highlighting for OP]

However, in a question from MSO, the highlighting is present:

> [image: screenshoot from MSO with highlighting for OP]

Can the OP get his/her highlighting back on MSE?

Comment: @hims056 thanks... who would have thought to search for "special color".

Comment: @Sha: Good experience to identify Eeekk! situations :D #balpha.

Comment: Obviously, my EEK-ness radar is off (although, I did only use 3 E's, so I knew it wasn't an EEEEEEEEK)

Comment: @hims056 is right, balpha has graciously de-eeekified more than one of my reports. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard but he left mine alone :) so maybe it was an EEEK?

Comment: @psubsee2003 because it's a dupe, he probably saw no point editing it. You can ask him directly, he won't bite! (but maybe he'll byte you ;-))